# Django: register template filter / tag per instance

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm using Django Template low-level libraries to parse some strings like this:

```
[..]
from django.template import Template, Context
options = Template('''{{% autoescape off %}}{0}{{% endautoescape %}}'''.format(options)).render(Context(self.context))
[..]
```

So, if I have a template instance like this:

```
template = Template('''{{% my_custom_tag %}} ''')
```

how can i programmatically register `my_custom_tag` as a simple_tag (`django.template.Library.simple_tag()`) in my execution context? I know you can register it *globally* with `django.template.Library()`, but I only want this tag (or a filter) in this context.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you would want this.

Registering a template tag doesn't mean you can use it any particular template. For that, you have to call `{% load %}` on the templatetags file it is contained in. So, if you don't want a tag to be available in a template, don't load it.